# How to replace space with \(space) using sed?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

When I use sed to replace all the spaces with X, the command works, the command being:

```
sed 's/ /X/g' filelist.tmp
```

However, when I try the same to replace all occurrences of space with \space, the code being :

```
sed 's/ /\ /g' filelist.tmp
```

It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Note that I'm new to shell scripting.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add another `\` i.e. you need to make `\` literal:

```
sed 's/ /\\ /g'
```

With only a single `\` before space, the `\` is escaping the following space; as the space is not a special character in replacement that needs escaping, it is being taken as is.

**Example:**

```
% sed 's/ /\\ /g' <<<'foo  bar  spam'
foo\ \ bar\ \ spam
```

Comment: Tried it. No change occured. My code was : `sed "s/ /\\ /g" filelist.tmp`. It didn't work!

Comment: @SomenathSinha No, use single quotes like i have used, otherwise you will go through shell escaping. Do: `sed 's/ /\\ /g'`

Comment: That worked! Why wasn't it working with double quotes?

Comment: @SomenathSinha If you use double quotes, the shell will interpret the `\\`s and will leave a single `\` for `sed`, so `sed` will have `s/ /\ /g`, which won't work as you can see now.

Answer (score 3):

You should use -r argument and should fix syntax to

```
sed -r "s/\s/\\\s/g" filelist.tmp
```

You have mistake in order of escaping "\" also.