# How To Replace Space With Another Space And Character

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I'm trying to use the following command:

`sed 's/\s/\s\#/g'`

This supposedly would take this:

`My Awesome Example Text`

And Change It To:

`My #Awesome #Example #Text`

However, I can't get it to do that. I tried a few slashes and escaping it. What would be the proper `sed` command for this? I looked up a few other articles (below), but they didn't have the answer using a literal `\s`.

Tried:

- [How to replace space with \(space) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41662400/how-to-replace-space-with-space-using-sed)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/431167/sed-replace-all-tabs-and-spaces-with-a-single-space

Comment: `sed 's/ /&#/g' file` where `&` is back-reference of matched text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
sed 's/ /&#/g' file
```

where `&` is back-reference of matched text.

If you want to match space or tab then use:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]/&#/g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat text
My Awesome Example Text

$ sed 's/ / #/g' text 
My #Awesome #Example #Text
```

Comment: Simple enough. Was hoping to use `\s`. It works for now.